# Is there a way to increase FPS for already existing video?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, video, avfoundation

I want to make slow motion video more smoother, so as I understand I need to increase *FPS* for it. As I know we can use `ffmpeg` library for it, but is there more iOS-native way to increase *FPS* for video?